# In the Schwarz inequality, what happens when $a$ and $b$ lie on the opposite sides of the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra

The Schwarz inequality is an equality if and only if $b$ is a multiple of $a$. The angle is $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = 180$, so  $\cos \theta = 1$ or $-1$. In this case $b$ is identical with its projection $p$ and the distance between $b$ and the line is $0$. But what happens when $a$ and $b$ lie on the opposite sides of the origin?

Comment: Do you mean $a$ and $b$ are vectors, and $\theta$ is the angle between them?

Comment: By "in this case", do you mean the case that $\cos \theta = 1$, or the case that $\cos \theta = -1$, or both?

Comment: Yes to your first comment, and I meant both for the second comment. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The same happens: $b$ and it's projection are the same.